# How to implement AODV and GPSR protocols based on 80211p?

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

I implemented AODV and GPSR protocol existing in inet module on the senario network existing in veins-inet subproject.so, how to implement them based on 80211p ?
In other words , i want to use the upper layers of INET and lower layers of Veins?

I am using instant veins-4.7.1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use lower layers of Veins, you will need to write an adapter module yourself. Its design is straightforward: to upper layers, it will look like an INET NIC, to lower layers it will act like a Veins application.

Note, however, that recent versions of the INET Framework offer an easier way: their WLAN NIC can be configured to behave according to 802.11p. While this has not received as much use as the modules of Veins, it should serve as a reasonably-safe alternative in many applications.

See the `veins_inet` example of recent Veins versions for how to configure INET to model 802.11p VANETs and, at the same time, use Veins for ensuring realistic road traffic.